# Python // BS4 // Tags

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

If have the following html:

```
</br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_1a<br>TEXT_1b
                            </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_2a<br>TEXT_2b
                            </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_3a<br>TEXT_3b
                            </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_4a<br>TEXT_4b
                            </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_5a<br>TEXT_5b
                            </br></td>, <td class="first">TEXT_6a<br>TEXT_6b
```

I used

```
[i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('td.first')]
```

Hoever, then I got

```
   ['TEXT_1aTEXT_1b', 'TEXT_2aTEXT_2b', 'TEXT_3aTEXT_3b', 'TEXT_4aTEXT_4b', 'TEXT_5aTEXT_5b', 'TEXT_6aTEXT_6b']
```

How can I remove TEXT_1b,TEXT_2b...TEXT_nb. In addition I would like not to have an array but N1 = TEXT_1a, N2 = TEXT_2a...Nn = TEXT_na

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
[i.contents[0].strip() for i in soup.select('td.first')]
```

Regarding the 2nd part of your question - you want to have the fields in individual variables? You can do it, but it's probably not a great idea. Is there a reason for it?

Either, you know how many of them there are, in which case you can do:

```
n1, n2, n3, ...nN = [i.contents[0].strip() for i in soup.select('td.first')]
```

Or you don't, in which case an array (list, in python) is really the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: Worked fine. You are right. The array is the way to go, also simply due to calculation reasons. I did however pull the "cells" out of the array in order to write it into excel. Thanks again!